# why emBits = modBits — 1 in RSASSA-PSS

Tags: hash, cryptography, rsa

Standard(PKCS#1) says that length of message used to sign must be emBits = modBits — 1. But where is it from? I mean in this standard signature is based on a hash and hash is supplemented to a length emBits. But why is it must be modBits — 1? To create a digital signature of the right size?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's pretend you have a modulus value of `0b1010111111` (10 bits).

If you run `EMSA-PSS-Encode(M, 10)` it could (if capable of producing numbers that small) produce `0b1111001011`.  That value exceeds the modulus, so it's mathematically equivalent to `0b100001100`.  When running verify you get the intermediate value of `0b100001100`, then find that your signature fails to verify.  You sign it again, this time it works. Confusion abounds.

The answer, ultimately, is "to have a stable algorithm which gets as close to the modulus value as possible without exceeding it".  Similarly, `EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5` starts with a zero-byte, to ensure the modulus is always a larger number than the encoded value.